# Match names joined with a delimiter except last

Tags: regex

Let's suppose we have, in a text file, many rows containing each one multiple names joined with ";" delimiter except last name (which doesn't end with it).
We can use the following regex :

```
^(\w+;)+$  // Not good
```

The previous regex won't work because it forces last name, hence the whole row to end with a ";" also

Answer (score 2):

You could add matching a single `\w+` after it. If you don't need the capturing group, you might make it non capturing.

This way you are repeating matching word characters followed by a `;` and end the match with word characters.

```
^(?:\w+;)+\w+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\w+;` Match 1+ word chars followed by `;`
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxSQUG/1)

If a single word should also match, you could repeat the group 0+ times using `*` instead of `+`

```
^(?:\w+;)*\w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxSQUG/2)

Comment: Can I have some explanation and corresponding terms for what you used?

Comment: The problem is that, in fact **name** correspond to a kind of huge regex that we don't want to repeat again

Comment: @CfassKing you can always recurse it

Comment: @CinCout I have added another example to also match one entry.

Comment: What does **?:** stand for? Is there an appropriate call for that part?

Comment: @CfassKing I have extended the explanation. `(?:` is a non capturing group. [This page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) might be helpful.Which tool or language are you using?

Comment: Sorry 4 the late, I use VBA, let me check your link content. I'll be back.

Comment: @CinCout Can I know more about **recursing** you talked about earlier?